# Image is very blurry

Tags: css, custom-header

I'm using Tevolution. I can't find where I can re-size the flag at the top of this website: [isupportblack.com](http://www.isupportblack.com/) It is blurry and shouldn't be. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a question specific to WP. Questions of these types will suit more on Stackoverflow.

For your problem, add the following piece to your theme's style.css

```
a#directorytab img {
    width: 16%;
}
```

Let me know if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

The image you are trying to use is only 18x12px.. and is being stretched to fill 175% of the available width. and 50% of the available height.

Of course its blurry...

Use a larger image... or scale it down to the actual size..

for some reason you have

```
img {
    width: 175%;
    height: 50%;
}
```

On ALL your images..

If u want the image to be the same height and width of the ACTUAL image then try

```
#directorytab img{ width: 18px; height: 12px;}
```